# Convert SQL Stored procedure ResultSet table JSON to XML

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-logic-apps

This looks pretty obvious but somehow its not working for me. I am trying to build a solution in Logic App on Microsoft Azure but I am stuck to convert JSON object to XML.

My requirement is to execute a Stored Procedure and save the response in XML format. By default SQL Execute Stored Procedure Action returns the response in below JSON format,

```
    {
"OutputParameters": { },
"ReturnCode": 0,
"ResultSets": {
"Table1": [
      {
        "ProductID": 680,
        "Name": "HL Road Frame - Black, 58",
        "ProductNumber": "FR-R92B-58",
        "Color": "Black",
        "StandardCost": 1059.31,
        "ListPrice": 1431.5,
        "Size": "58",
        "Weight": 1016.04
      },
      {
        "ProductID": 706,
        "Name": "HL Road Frame - Red, 58",
        "ProductNumber": "FR-R92R-58",
        "Color": "Red",
        "StandardCost": 1059.31,
        "ListPrice": 1431.5,
        "Size": "58",
        "Weight": 1016.04
      }]
 }
}
```

Above response is then used in "Create Blob" action to save response in blob on Azure.

This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-definition-language) says that logic app provides xml function to convert string or JSON object to XML but this seems to be not working as expected. I tried below expression but nothing works,

1. @xml(body('Execute_stored_procedure')?['ResultSets'])

ERROR: The template language function 'xml' parameter is not valid. The provided value cannot be converted to XML: 'This document already has a 'DocumentElement' node.'. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#xml for usage details.

2. @xml(body('Execute_stored_procedure')?['ResultSets']['Table1'])

ERROR: The template language function 'xml' expects its parameter to be a string or an object. The provided value is of type 'Array'. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#xml for usage details.

All I want is to convert this JSON to an XML like below,

```
<Root><Product>....</Product><Product>....</Product></Root>
```

The alternate solution could be calling a Azure Function and convert this JSON to XML in c# code. But before I try alternate solution I want to know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After posting question I further analysed the issue and found that I was passing the wrong JSON object in @xml function.

The correct JSON object should be as below,

```
{
"ResultSets": {
"Table1": [
      {
        "ProductID": 680,
        "Name": "HL Road Frame - Black, 58",
        "ProductNumber": "FR-R92B-58",
        "Color": "Black",
        "StandardCost": 1059.31,
        "ListPrice": 1431.5,
        "Size": "58",
        "Weight": 1016.04
      },
      {
        "ProductID": 706,
        "Name": "HL Road Frame - Red, 58",
        "ProductNumber": "FR-R92R-58",
        "Color": "Red",
        "StandardCost": 1059.31,
        "ListPrice": 1431.5,
        "Size": "58",
        "Weight": 1016.04
      }]
 }
}
```

Please note that I had to remove below to lines,

```
"OutputParameters": { },
"ReturnCode": 0,
```

So tried with below expression and it worked,

```
@xml(json(concat('{\"ResultSets\":',body('Execute_stored_procedure').ResultSets,'}')))
```

Now I need to little tweak this expression to get the final XML. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Had similar issue only trying to provide array as root. When adding 'ResultSets' for example as root, then parsing works fine.

Answer (score 0):

In order to convert to XML, the JSON needs to have a single root element.

The first example has multiple elements at the root level, which is what the error message is complaining about in "This document already has a 'DocumentElement' node".

Your 'correct' JSON does have a single root element.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20644640)

Comment: @GerhardBarnard look again, this is an answer. It states OP's JSON is malformed and can't be converted because it can only have a single root element.